# find max column value in r conditional on another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of baseball player information:

```
        playerID nameFirst nameLast bats throws yearID stint teamID lgID   G  AB   R   H X2B X3B HR RBI SB CS BB  SO IBB
81955  rolliji01     Jimmy  Rollins    B      R   2007     1    PHI   NL 162 716 139 212  38  20 30  94 41  6 49  85   5
103358 wilsowi02    Willie   Wilson    B      R   1980     1    KCA   AL 161 705 133 230  28  15  3  49 79 10 28  81   3
93082  suzukic01    Ichiro   Suzuki    L      R   2004     1    SEA   AL 161 704 101 262  24   5  8  60 36 11 49  63  19
83973  samueju01      Juan   Samuel    R      R   1984     1    PHI   NL 160 701 105 191  36  19 15  69 72 15 28 168   2
15201   cashda01      Dave     Cash    R      R   1975     1    PHI   NL 162 699 111 213  40   3  4  57 13  6 56  34   5
75531  pierrju01      Juan   Pierre    L      L   2006     1    CHN   NL 162 699  87 204  32  13  3  40 58 20 32  38   0
       HBP SH SF GIDP   average
81955    7  0  6   11 0.2960894
103358   6  5  1    4 0.3262411
93082    4  2  3    6 0.3721591
83973    7  0  1    6 0.2724679
15201    4  0  7    8 0.3047210
75531    8 10  1    6 0.2918455
```

I want to return a maximum value of the batting average ('average') column  where the at-bats ('AB') are greater than 100. There are also 'NaN' in the average column.

Comment: `df %>% filter(AB >100) %>% summarise(max = max(average, na.rm = TRUE))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the entire row for which the two conditions are `TRUE`, you can do something like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  AB = sample(seq(50, 150, 10), 10),
  avg = c(runif(9), NaN)
)

data %>%
  filter(AB >= 100) %>%
  filter(avg == max(avg, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Where the first filter is to only keep rows where AB is greater than or equal to 100 and the second filter is to select the entire row where it is max. If you want to to only get the maximum value, you can do something like this:

```
data %>%
  filter(AB >= 100) %>%
  summarise(max = max(avg, na.rm = TRUE))
```